# grup error while installing windows 7

Tags: windows-7, grub

i changed my HD and i can not install win7 from the DVD even if it is the 1st boot in bios it always get to Grup and give an error: No sash partition, any help with this?

Comment: Can you do anything with that disk?  Do you see what looks like reasonable information through your bios setup?  Have you double-checked your cables and any jumper settings?

Comment: Yes every thing is right now i tired to boot from USB with ubunot and it works the problem is with DVD i think